# Intermittent Google maps api Authorization Error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Today we witnessed intermittent errors with google maps api on the browser.

> Google has disabled use of the Maps for this application. The provided
>   key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the
>   Google Maps API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps
>   Javascript API V3 on this site.

On the developer console, all the map apis are enabled.

- Also the "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" usage is well under the free 25k requests/day.
- It's showing 100% success rate of all requests
- Requests per second average on the graph is 0.025 maximum.

I am not sure what changed causing google maps api to throw this error.

We are using v3 api showing maps:

```
script.src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key='+mapKey+'&language=en-IN&sensor=true&libraries=places&callback=loadInfoBox';
```

Is there a way to know what is the actual cause of the error?

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem on our app.  
According to The API's traffic report on the [developer's console] (https://console.developers.google.com) our usage is no where near the quota limit.

Comment: I just noticed the same on one of my websites where this never occured before. Temporary issue on Google side?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Seems to happen since yesterday.

Comment: We're also getting the same intermittent issue.

Comment: There's an open bug report on this issue:  
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7464

Comment: Same problem here. Just to add: I generated a new API key in [the developers console](https://console.developers.google.com) and deployed the change to my site but I am still getting the error intermittently.

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486527/google-maps-api-randomly-displays-javascript-alert-saying-the-api-key-is-invalid

Comment: The bug report has been confirmed by Google today

Answer (score 1):

[According to the official issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7464), this issue should be resolved now.