# Google Maps API randomly displays JavaScript-alert saying the API key is invalid

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

### The problem

We have been successfully using the Google Maps API on our website for a long time. We switched from v2 to v3 almost two years ago, without any problems. But since today, we sometimes see JavaScript-alerts popping up on our pages. The issue might be around for a longer time, but we only noticed today. The alerts are not displayed on every pageview, but around once out of twenty pageviews with Google Maps (estimate). The alerts contain the following error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

You can see the alert in action right here: http://www.uitzendbureau.nl/uitzendbureaus/boxmeer (and on all other pages on our website with Google Maps; note that it only shows up about once out of twenty pageviews).

### Researched possible causes

#### Recent changes

We did not make any related changes in our code, we didn't use a new auth key and there were no other actions on our side that could have caused this.

#### Experimental version

A few hours ago, we noticed we might be using the experimental version of the API, because we did not include an API version in our request. I added `v=3`, but this did not fix the issue.

#### Authentication key

We use the same key on both our development and live environment (on a different domain), and both environments display the same error. I tried to generate a new auth key, but the new key gave us the same results.

#### API request limitations

I suppose this cannot be caused by exceeding the API limits. Yes, we do exceed the 25k map loads several days a week, but I quote the following from https://developers.google.com/maps/usagelimits/:

> **What happens if I go over the limit?**
> If your website surpasses 25,000 map loads per day for 90 consecutive days, Google will attempt to contact you with information about payment options. At this time, we will specify a purchase deadline; until this deadline, your website will continue to work as expected with no change to how maps appear.
> Once the deadline has passed, if you have neither enabled billing nor purchased a Google Maps API for Work license by this deadline, the maps on your website will continue to work, but only for the first 25,000 map loads each day. Beyond this number, the Maps API will cease to function.

We were never contacted by Google, and we were never given a deadline.

Several hours ago, we tried increasing the per user rate limit from 1 req per user per second to 2 reqs per user per second. That didn't make any difference so far, but I'm not sure how long this change would take to be applied. However, I don't think we hit this limit because I still see the error message on pages with only one map, while refreshing the page at a very slow rate.

### Update

Google has confirmed and fixed this bug in their API: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7464

Comment: Duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479634/intermittent-google-maps-api-authorization-error